# Cocos2d-Android run app on many devices

Tags: android, cocos2d-android, android-screen-support

I want to make cocos2d game for android that run on every device. I have idea to resize images when application is loaded for first time. I have some questions about that. Is this good idea? Can I save resized images on `assets` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking it would work technically but will lead to lower image quality due to upscaling or downscaling issues. You can hardly achieve the same image quality when scaling images on the device compared to doing that using an image program.

The preferable approach is to design images for all supported resolutions, and only if the device resolution is marginably different use the same assets but merely layout them slightly differently.

Comment: Hi LearnCocos2D, I am new in cocos2d game development. Can you give me brief idea about design layouts for multi-resolution devices in android?

Comment: hi LearnCocos2D, I am new in cocos2d game development. Can you give me idea about multi-resolution for devices in android?please help me.